# Simple VBA loop error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file, which has horribly many rows, in column A, if pasted to excel.
So I wanted excel to make it to table.
I tried to make a simple VBA loop system, which makes the tables just like I want. Without looping, the code would be horribly wrong. 
But the problem is that I don't know how to change cells after each loop. Here is the code, I tried:

```
Sub 123()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim u As Integer
i = 5
ii = 8
u = 5
Do Until i > 20
    Range("A,i:A,ii").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B,u").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    i = i + 4
    ii = ii + 4
    u = u + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I made that solution up, from some instructions. Maybe you can help me to find the easiest solution here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with your explanation, the lines highlighted below will cause an error as you're using variables within double quotes:

```
Range("A,i:A,ii").Select
```

and

```
Range("B,u").Select
```

Change them to the following to concatenate the value:

```
Range("A" & i & ":A" & ii).Select
Range("B" & u).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean s.th. like this?

```
Sub 123()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim u As Integer
i = 5
ii = 8
u = 5
Do Until i > 20
    Range("A" & i & ":A" & ii).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B" & u).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    i = i + 4
    ii = ii + 4
    u = u + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I think this will work, but it is not very nice.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! ^_^
I'm a real newbie, so making it beautiful isnt priority atm. :P
Thank you!